# How to add new segments on polygon using input scribbles from users

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry, 2d

I want to create a UI to do polygon editing. My input is a vector image (cubic bezier). The main goal is users are able to draw scribbles to create new segments on the polygon, so it's like semi-automatic polygon drawing by considering the existing polygon.

[image]

Based on assumption the users input is drawn using a mouse, so it's typically rough and quite imprecise.

The new segments aren't only straight lines but also curves, So I think the new segments should also conform the rough input of the users:
[image]

Another case:

[image]

Is this solvable? Any feedback is really appreciated, I also want to know if there's any paper with similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem,

I used Euler Spiral

http://www.lems.brown.edu/vision/researchAreas/EulerSpiral/

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to start with :-

> 1. Do connected components on the image to get user scribbles
> 2. try and fit the scribbles to line,circle,parabola..
> 3. Whichever gives the minimum squared error is the desired curve
> 4. Draw the desired curve between the endpoints of scribble.

**References:-**

[Connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)

[Curve Fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting)

Comment: I know curve fitting, but the resulting curve should also take account on existing segments (see example 2, the two curves should form a circle although the scribbles isn't good enough)